# Android - registering and verifying through email addresses

Tags: android

I'm building an app similar to Whatsapp, where I'd like to sync phone contacts into my app that are an existing users of the service. I was planning on registering devices by sending a loopback SMS to the device and picking up the phone number for registering at my web service for push notifications. However, bearing in mind that some devices (like Android tablets) don't actually have a phone number, I thought that I'd use email verification as a secondary option.

The question is how do I verify email addresses in a short and easy way? If I send a verification email back to the user, they'd have to leave the app, go into their browser, check their email and go to the verification link before coming back to the app. Any thoughts?

If I decide to use verification email, can an app be called using javascript or an HTML hyperlink from the verification page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question: yes, you can use a custom Uri scheme that your app would accept. (like how the "market://..." links work).

This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448531/1115453