# Extend browser functionality in Android

Tags: android

When I open the Android's default browser I want to add a button or a menu entry when it's clicked to open my Intent and pass me the current url parameter.

Is this possible in Android?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: the button, will be inside the browser, as an html element?

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon inside the browser.Just like chrome extensions for Windows.

Comment: AFAIK, The android default browser does not support such an element which can behave like an exension, and persist across pages. Browsers Dolphin and Firefox support such extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only by means of the Share option, if the browser in question has one. The standard AOSP Browser app will have such a "Share" option in the action overflow. It triggers an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, with a MIME type of `text/plain`, so any activities claiming to support that in the manifest via an `<intent-filter>` will be able to respond:

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can get the current url:

```
URL url = new URL(mWebView.getUrl());
```

Comment: That is `WebView`, not "the browser".

Comment: OK sorry, misunderstood the question then

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood this right, but I think this what you want.

When the user clicks your button, you can redirect to a custom url, `somesite://current_page_url.` using javascript or the addon's capability.

That can be picked up by your intent filter with host set to "somesite", as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448531/759019).