# Clickable video using Youtube native App

Tags: android, youtube

I used this code to play youtube video using native youtube app.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:zAhzo0JCbFY")).putExtra("force_fullscreen",true));
```

It works fine. But thing is its a clickable video like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAhzo0JCbFY
```

Youtube app doesn't allow the links to be clicked. Is there anything to be done(only with native youtube app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***SORRY***

The only thing you can do is to wait for the YouTube app to implement this.

***BUT***

You can find some alternative, including showing the video in a webview (if you manage), showing the links natively (if you have them), or just using the browser.

In all these cases, it is not the Youtube app.

Comment: So I will be waiting for youtube app to implement this. I don't have any links. Actually they are not static links... Videos change dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `<intent-filter>`. I do not now the exact procedure but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android/2448531#2448531) explains it well.