# How to use intents for Android custom URL schema?

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, custom-url

Basically I have the same question as described in [How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android)

I followed the instructions from the answered questions and added to my android manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyUriActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="path" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also, I added a new activity like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyUriActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        System.out.println("URI CLICKED!");
    }
}
```

My Android app is based on Phonegap, so I simply added a link to my index.html like this:

```
<a href="myapp://foo">Click me</a>
```

When I clicked, I see in my console the following error:

```
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629): Error loading url myapp://foo
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=myapp://foo }
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(CordovaWebViewClient.java:209)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:274)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:376)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-14 12:23:16.177: E/Cordova(629):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So it seems like I am missing the activity. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You didn't call `super.onCreate(b);`
2. Url `myapp://foo` doesn't match your `IntentFilter`. It should be `myapp://path/` or you can change the `IntentFilter` and remove `host` part.

   ```
   <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
   ```