# Android App: How to read get parameters from a custom url scheme?

Tags: android, url, android-activity, url-scheme

Basically, I have the same question described as in [How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android)

The answer given there works for me. When the custom url is called `MyUriActivity's` methods `onCreate` and `onStart` are called.

**BUT**

How can I access the get parameters from within `MyUriActivity`?

Example:

`myapp://path/to/what/i/want?d=This%20is%20a%20test`

In `MyUriActivity` I need to read the value of get parameter `d`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Call `getIntent().getData()` to retrieve [the `Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html), then call `getQueryParameter("d")` on it to get the value of `d`.

Comment: Worked for me, perfect answer...!