# Opening specific screen in native app with qr code?

Tags: android, uri, qr-code

Using a URL in a QR code, is it possible to open a native app, and then extract data from the query string in the URL to do something specific within the app?

I have membership site with a QR code generator on it, which allows members to make a QR code containing the URL of their public membership page eg www.mysite.com/members/54663. The public can then scan the user's code to get to their page.

It works great for using the web-app version of my site, but now I have an Android version of the app.

I think I understand how to open my native app via a clicked QR code, but I'm wondering if it's possible to extract data out of the url too? If I use a URI scheme to trigger opening my Android app with the above QR code, can my app then extract the 54663? Say, if the embedded url was www.mysite.com?user=54663 ? Or can a uri scheme only open a native app, and not do anything further.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Duplicate of [Android App: How to read get parameters from a custom url scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063696/android-app-how-to-read-get-parameters-from-a-custom-url-scheme). The fact that this is starting from a QR code, versus an ordinary hyperlink or some other source, should not matter.

Comment: Thanks for that CommonsWare