# Android - Getting link from which Activity is started

Tags: android, email

Currently I'm working on user registration form which uses email confirmation.

I've managed to start my app using link in the email, but I have no clue on getting the link which user clicked to start my app.

The link is somewhat like this :

`www.lalala.com/CfmEmail?Token=12345&code=ASDfghJKLzxc&Email=kevin@gmail.com`

I want to break it down to get its individual value like

`Token = 12345`, `Email = kevin@gmail.com` and `Code = ASDfghJKLzxc`

Please do notify me for any further essential information..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17063750/1239966

Comment: Woot so it's called uri reading parameter from custom URL, thanks! Your answered helped a lot! And shame I didn't know the term so I couldn't research it before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known as deep linking. For implementation check [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)