# Android: Extracting attributes with '+' sign from a uri

Tags: android, uri

I'm getting a data Uri out of my intent and try to parse the attributes. However, if the attribute contains a '+' sign, the `getQueryParameter(attr)` method will convert it to a ' ' as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameter(java.lang.String))

So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063696/android-app-how-to-read-get-parameters-from-a-custom-url-scheme) wont work if the parameter contains a '+' sign.

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-on-android) is converting the '+' to a '_'

My Uri looks somehow like this: `"MyApp:///?Attr=fdwGcv+fsdsfd_AS="`

Answer (score 0):

Encode all the query parameter while creating the url.

```
String url = null;
    try {
        url = "MyApp:///?attr=" + URLEncoder.encode("fdwGcv+fsdsfd_AS=", "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    System.out.print("attr::"+uri.getQueryParameter("attr"));
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? It is returning null. Even when calling getQueryParameterNames() it returns a Set with size 0\

Comment: The code is tested please check -  I am using "uri.getQueryParameter("attr")" method

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't find it very convenient. How would the code change if I have more than one parameter separated with &. Why should I hard code the first parameter of the encode method?

Comment: The answer is just to show how to encode the query parameter. you have to encode the query parameter before adding to url , if it has any special character check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url. All the method like getQueryParameterNames()  will still works and no need to hardcode anything.