# Redirect Android webview with intent filter

Tags: android, webview, intentfilter

I have a specific URL that I want redirected to a specific activity in my app from a webview with an intent filter. [How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android/2448531#2448531) described how to do this for a browser page, but this same intent filter doesn't work when that URL is accessed through the webview. Is there anything else that needs to be added to this intent filter to catch these webview links?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:host="myurl.com/stuff" android:scheme="http"></data>
  </intent-filter>`
```

Answer (score 4):

I have not got intent filters and webviews to work together just with declaring the intent on the manifest and I think they are not supposed to. (I wonder why...) I think the way to do it is catching urls when you are trying to open them in the webview and creating an intent then.

Then, for an activity register as follows in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".PretendChat">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="chat" ></data>
            <data android:scheme="testing"></data>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*"></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You would expect the activity PretendChat opens when you click on a link like the following: "testing://chat" inside the webview. In order for that to happen you
would need the following code on the webview client you are using on the webview. Assume that the activity that starts the webview is called WebviewActivity.

```
private  class TestWebViewClient extends WebViewClient       {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            WebviewActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


        }   catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            Log.e(LOGTAG,"Could not load url"+url);
        }

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    


    }
}
```

Comment: This solution only work in case if you have the control over the webview i.e. where the webView object implementation  source code  you are overriding. what about when this webview is in the compile/jar/libarary form and you don't have source code to modify it.Then how we will redirect to some activity based on specfic URL, this is the question

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got it to work was to use a dummy file link and loading the URL with loadDataWithBaseURL and using relative links in the data. The latest WebView only seems to accept valid links, and I couldn't get it to work with custom intents for Activities.

If I tried a different scheme, such as "my-app" instead of "file", the url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading would come up as "about:blank".

I also wanted to pass parameters to the activity to be opened in Bundle.

```
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset", w.Definition, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.startsWith("file")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DictWordActivity.this, DictWordActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("word", Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment());
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                    } else
                        return false;
                }
            });
```

I created my relative links like this:

```
"<a href=\"" + word + "\">" + word + "</a>");
```

If anyone has a better solution I would like to know.