# How to open Activity on hyperlink click in sms

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to copy a link on button click , user can paste that hyper link anywhere in sms or email or nay other app ,that hyperlink launch app and open Activity  say Userplots

how i pass data to intent-Filter, to get this functionality

thanks for any help

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android you would want to define a url scheme (or you can use intent URIs...)

Comment: can you give me some example? when i copy link, it do nothing, my link is myapp://plotid=13

Comment: Look at the answer. You need to declare an IntentFilter in your manifest and create a receiver class to handle it.

Comment: how i make other activity to receive action, with a broad cast receiver or Intent-filter do it