# how to open app through custom URL schema?

Tags: android, cordova

I need to open my application through custom URL schema in phone gap android application

when call my custom link in Firefox browser it will automatically redirects to my app.

But i am using chrome or default browser it will not redirect to my app,it redirect to Google search.

I need open my app in all android browsers.

If any one know the solution please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android)