# how to launch windows phone app via browser url

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to windows phone app development. Is it possible to open windows phone app via browser url. If possible, please someone help me.

[How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android)

please visit the above url;

but its possible in the android

```java
 <activity
        android:name="TabHost"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="myschema" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

below code is working in windows 8 desktop IE Browser

but its not working in the windows phone

```cs
<Applications>
 <Application Id="SDKSample.App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"                                     EntryPoint="SDKSample.App">
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.protocol">
      <Protocol Name="alsdkcs" m2:DesiredView="useLess"/>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <FileTypeAssociation Name=".alsdkcs" m2:DesiredView="useLess">
        <SupportedFileTypes>
          <FileType>.alsdkcs</FileType>
        </SupportedFileTypes>
      </FileTypeAssociation>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
  <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="Launcher API C# sample" Description="AssociationLaunching C# sample" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#00b2f0" Square150x150Logo="Assets\squaretile-sdk.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\smallTile-Phone-sdk.png">
    <m3:DefaultTile ShortName="Launcher API C#" DefaultSize="square150x150Logo" Wide310x150Logo="Assets\tile-sdk.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\mediumtile-sdk.png">
      <m3:ShowNameOnTiles>
        <m3:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo"/>
        <m3:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo"/>
      </m3:ShowNameOnTiles>
    </m3:DefaultTile>
    <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\splash-Phone-sdk.png" BackgroundColor="#00b2f0"/>
    <m3:ApplicationView MinWidth="width320"/>
  </m3:VisualElements>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hell... I got the answer. It's working if I call via javascript

```cs
<input id="btnwindowsphone" type="button" class="button" name="" value="open windows phone"      onclick="javascript:loadwindowsphone();" /><br /><br />
```

```cs
function loadwindowsphone() {
                     window.location = 'alsdkcs://hd';
                 }
```

Comment: Nice !! Very useful !!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same for Windows phone - registering custom URI scheme that will open your app.

Here are some resources for you:

- [Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [URI schemes for launching built-in apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: i have tried pasting mailto:test@gmail.com in the windows phone browser url. i got unsupported address

Comment: i have tried everything mentioned in the above two url but only thing i am getting is unsupported address

Comment: Why would that work? Did you register your app for mailto URI? I don't think that is possible, but I may be wrong.

Comment: <Extensions>
      <Protocol Name="myprotocol" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
    </Extensions>

Comment: have you ever did this. need to launch the via browser like myprotocol://parameters

Answer (score 0):

This documentation article works for Windows Phone 8.1 / Windows Phone 10 Mobile:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx

If you're running into issues not being able to open the URI scheme you registered it's most likely because you're trying to open it using Internet Explorer / Edge. This will not work.

Instead send yourself an email containing the link or put it down into OneNote - just an external place, that actually links into the browser.

Otherwise IE / Edge will treat your scheme as http://myscheme/ instead of myscheme://.