# Android app not opening from URL using intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open my app from a website and read some text from link. The URL will be like `codespike.com/?code=xxxx`. I need to read the `xxx` but my problem is that I am not able to open my app when this specific URL in being opened in the browser. For testing I also used a webiste `bfinstafollowers.com`, not working with this either.
This is what I am trying.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.softech.betforinstafollowers.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:host="bfinstafollowers.com" android:scheme="http"
                    android:pathPrefix=".*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

also tried with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>` and without `android:pathPrefix=".*"` but my app doesnt open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android)

Comment: @Fahim already checked that. didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue, as it turns out regular `http`, `https` doesn't work. I had to create my custom scheme for this purposes.