# facebook example deep link

Tags: android, facebook, api

i am trying to create a deep link for my app on facebook.

All their examples have been written by people who like words a lot.

If my app url is `a.b.c`  and the app is called `c` what do i put in the purple highlighted box to open the app? Note that i don't care about sending any data to the app - we are just going to open the app in the same way as opening it from the ... whatever it is called, when you press on the app icon.

[image: how are there so many words used by the facebook team to say what to put here???]

Comment: I'm suffering from the same problem, I read all what they have written and still I don't understand the flow of using deep linking, do I make a Graph API request with the link I want to share on a personal wall so I get receive a - what they call - deep link? I followed all their steps but still I can't get it working because they don't provide a full example to explain the flow of their logic / process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at creating a URI scheme for your app. You need to create one and add it to your manifest file (on iOS, to the plist).

See this answer for **Android manifest**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448531

Bonus: here's how you add it to the **plist on iOS**.
[image]

Then you **type that same URI scheme into the box** you see on Facebook.

Comment: it's for a iOS application. i need for android application please help for generating deep link

Comment: I linked to another SO answer for Android