# Launching an app from another app

Tags: android

I have made 2 apps. In the first app there is a string and a  button. I want that after clicking on the button, the second app should be opened and that string should be passed to that app. How is this possible.
This is my primary requirement. It would be great if the second app can not be opened directly. Only way to open it is by clicking on the button in the first app. If this is possible then let me know.

I am new to android so please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using implicit intent check [Receiving/calling implicit intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) 
and 

**Edit**
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: I wish to use explicit intent. Is it possible

Comment: yeah I did. How should I pass the string. And the second app can be opened directly as well. Any way to stop that?

Comment: @palakarora you can use `intent.putString()` for passing string and is you don't want to show second app in home then remove `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` from AndroidManifest

Comment: how will the second app receive the string. and do I need to make any changes to the manifest of second app like adding intent filters or something like this

Comment: @palakarora put srting using  `intent.putExtra(key,value)` for receiving string second app you have to use `getIntent.getStringExtra(key)` in activity that will start

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
    String app_Name ="com.package.name";
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app_Name);
    if (intent != null) {
        // Activity now start the activity
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", "Your variable Here");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        //Go to the market  
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + app_Name));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

`app_Name` is variable.

Comment: how can I pass the string and where should I specify the name of the other app. I am sorry but I am new to android. Kindly help

Comment: `getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");` change `com.package.name`

Comment: How can I pass the string

Comment: Try `intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", "Your variable Here");` and `intent.getStringExtra` method .

Comment: Do I need to add some sort of intent filters in the other app which receives the string

Comment: yes.. Or decombile other app and know intent details .

Comment: I am the one whose making the second app. so what changes should I make in the manifest