# Open Android App with custom URL from PDF file

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, intentfilter, custom-url

I wish to let my Andorid App handle custom URLs like shown in this question:[How to implement own URI scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android).

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I've added links such as myapp://test to a PDF file, but when opening the file in Adobe Reader and clicking on the link, nothing happens.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It should be ok unless PDF is doing some URL filtering. You need to update your Android Manifest to support the new scheme as well. You should edit your request and add code so we can see why it might not be triggering your application.

Comment: Great, now I recommend you make an HTML file with test links to "myapp://" and see if that works. Eliminate Adobe Reader as a possible point of failure.

Comment: BTW: do you really think that `myapp` scheme is going to be unique?

Comment: @Cookster It works with HTML files... I'll double check the links in the PDF file.

Comment: I double checked the links in the PDF file and seem correct. I guess Adobe Reader is filtering the URL. Maybe I'll try with another PDF reader software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adobe Reader app seems to block unknown URLs since everything works fine with other PDF reader apps such as the built in  PDF Viewer in Dropbox.

Comment: Is there any way to unblock ?