# Opening the android app using a deep link

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-deep-link

My requirement is, There is an advertisement in an email for a shoe, if I click on that ad, it should open my app directly and take me to corresponding page without asking any available option like web browser, etc.

I tried Deep linking fundamental, But I don't know how to create deep links, from where I can get custom scheme(eg. testlink://test). 
for eg. google play scheme is market://details/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To enable Google to crawl your app content and allow users to enter your app from search results, you must add intent filters for the relevant activities in your app manifest.

refer  https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app

Answer (score 0):

There are actual several questions at play here:
1 - You need to know how to create a URI scheme(the testlink:// protocol you reference).
2 - You need to make your app do something when the end user clicks on the deep link.

To begin at the beginning, you don't "get" the custom scheme from anywhere, you create a URI scheme as part of setting up your app.  There is no real standardization as to what that scheme should be (despite some attempts).

The question of how to do this have been answered elsewhere ([How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android) and in the android docs).

And I actually just published a blog post with some suggestions on how to optimize that URI scheme (https://blog.branch.io/creating-uri-schemes-for-app-content-discovery).

The second question is easier.  Once you have that scheme in place, a user who

(a) clicks on a link that matches your scheme 
(b) has your app installed and 
(c) doesn't have some other app installed which uses the same scheme and which they've already set as the default for that scheme

will be launched directly into your app to the exact location / experience that you defined when you were setting up your intent filters.

Now if you want your deep links to work for users who don't already have your app installed you'll need to use a deferred/contextual deeplinking service.  Obviously I'm inclined towards Branch.io since I work for them, but I work for them because I think they have the best offering.

Regarding your last requirement, that there be no browser pop in between, the browser pop is usually part of the flow because it allows a deep linking service to pass some information to their servers about the user on click so that if the user *does not* have the app they can be directed to the app store and if they *do* have the app it can be launched by invoking your URI scheme.  If you want to do any sort of matching between click and install for users who do not already have the app or pass any info from the click to the app once it launches it been simply unavoidable until now.  [Universal links](https://blog.branch.io/best-practices-for-ios-9-universal-links) on iOS (new in iOS9) change that.  They can be invoked directly without needing to go through the browser and pass data directly into the app being launched, which is a pretty big deal.  Google is expected to announce an equivalent for Android in the very near future. The setup is  a bit intense, but worth it for the improved user experience.

Good luck!