# Start any android app with browser

Tags: android, browser, hyperlink, launch

I want to make a webpage from which you can launch any Android app. For example, I make a link with google maps/gmail/youtube/music etc and if I press the link it will open the app on my phone.

I found this code to open apps:

```
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end"> chrome</a><br>    
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=geo;package=com.google.android.apps.maps;end"> MAPS</a><br>
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=vnd.youtube;package=com.google.android.youtube;end"> youtube</a><br>
```

If I don't know the correct "scheme=", it will open only in the play store and not open the app.

So my question is how can I get the correct scheme for any app (which is made by Google, Microsoft, Sony, Samsung, and so on). Any there any other methods to launch any app through the browser in my phone?

Comment: That's not possible. To put it simply, apps have intent filters to specify what intents they can take as startup command, and those intents can be different per app. There is no universal one

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android

Comment: Ok, then how i can get the Google play music app intents?