# Android open application from QR Codee

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I create QR Code and after scanning it with QR Code reader, I need to start my application(android oo ios that sepondes the platform) maybe it will looks something like this : myApp://org.hardartcore.myApp?myParams or maybe something similar to this, are there any suggestions.

Comment: Does this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android

Comment: thank u Diogo, but i working on a wab application