# How to check using jsp whether an app is installed in mobile or not?

Tags: javascript, java, android, jsp, mobile

I am working on a mobile website. We are showing a default screen on mobile website with 2 options.
1. Open in app
2. Continue to mobile site

now I have to check when user chooses Open in App, if App is already installed on mobile, open App. 
If not go to play store.
Right now it is going to play store anyway.
How can I verify this, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register an intent filter for a specific URI in the manifest. Whenever the URI is resolved by the system (for example when you click on it in the browser) you application would be notified and could start up. See also [this so entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android?lq=1). But that does not handle the automatic redirect to the play store if the app is not installed. Maybe [deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) could do the job for you. [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICaeIFZJyN8) may also be relevant for deep linking.

Comment: Thanks GPuschka, now my webapp is able to call my android app, Intent filter were already written in my android app. I just added this link in webapp. intent://m.mysite.com#Intent;scheme=myscheme;package=maypackage id;end              here m.mysite,com, scheme and package was already mentioned in our android app.   now I have to do the same for iOS app