# Null query parameter from deeplink

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

I have implemented deep linking into my android application, Everything is working fine except for getting query parameters from the URL.

I am following the instructions at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android) to get parameters.

The URL looks like this:

```
myapp://path/want?a=123&b=345
```

I am doing something like this:

deeplink :- myapp://path/want?a=first&b=second

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
String valueOne = uri.getQueryParameter("a");
String valueTwo = uri.getQueryParameter("b");
```

I am getting the correct value of "valueOne" but getting null for "valueTwo", and I can't figure out why.

Comment: try checking value of b, before you pass it to URI

Comment: its is providing value

Comment: have you tried browsing same url with params from a browser?

Comment: I edited this, assuming you're using branch.io. If you're not, please remove that tag. :)

Comment: @McAdam331 this is not a Branch.io implementation, but thanks for the shoutout! (Branch team member here). [Branch.io](https://branch.io) would be a great alternative solution, and has the benefit of also working with Chrome (which URI strings like this will not)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been awhile.. hope this can help somebody:

I hit the same issue recently.

- If testing a deep link in command line `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "http://test.com/service1?param1=value1&param2=value2"` **only first query parameter is kept**. (`&param2=value2` is dropped) *Looks like a bug*.
- If testing a deep link by clicking the highlighted link in gmail (in my case I use google keep note) **all parameters are being passed as expected**