# Native Share Button - WhatsApp, FB und co

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, twitter, share

I am looking for a list for all "native share" buttons.

Like

```
href="whatsapp://
```

and i think there are more `like href="fb://` or `href="snapchat://`

PS: Do they have a special name?

Comment: They're called "custom URL schemes". https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html for iOS and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android for Android. I'm not aware of any comprehensive list of them - there are some spreadsheets in https://www.reddit.com/r/workflow/comments/3mux7h/ios_url_schemes/ that may be useful.

Comment: I am a little bit disappointed. Nobody has created a jquery share custom URL scheme plugin with fallback already. Thank you for the fast answer.