# azure mobile app authentication external redirect url

Tags: azure, url, redirect, azure-mobile-services

I have created **Azure Mobile App** and I am following official docs for this. During **Authentication** part of the docs following is stated

> In the Allowed External Redirect URLs, enter **url_scheme_of_your_app://easyauth.callback**. The url_scheme_of_your_app in this string is the URL Scheme for your mobile application. It should follow normal URL specification for a protocol (use letters and numbers only, and start with a letter). You should make a note of the string that you choose as you will need to adjust your mobile application code with the URL Scheme in several places.

My **Question** is that they havent provided any valid example for **redirect url** so I pasted **url_scheme_of_your_app://easyauth.callback** in my redirect url in the portal and it gives error because it isnt a valid format, so can anyone please give me a valid example for this url?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Here is a reference to the [url scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android). +1 if it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 11):

To anyone still struggling to figure out what exactly is the "MobileAppUrl", "url_scheme_of_your_app" and "redirectUriScheme" in Azure, here is an example: Assuming that your Azure Mobile App is called *myapp*, you will have the following:

**Mobile App URL:** `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net`

**url_scheme_of_your_app:** `myapp`

**redirectUriScheme:** `myapp://easyauth.callback`

It is also useful to know that an "Allowed External Redirect URL" for your Authentication settings in Azure Portal, would be:

`myapp://easyauth.callback`

Comment: An added note here, when you invoke the `.auth/login/{provider}` endpoint, to have it redirect to that external url the `post_login_redirect_uri` query param must be included. For example: `xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{provider}?post_login_redirect_uri=myapp://easyauth.callback`

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote **MyAppName** my app name is actually the app name of my app in azure portal, MyAppName://easyauth.callback     just like this and it was succesfully saved