# Can I open a map from an address onclick in chrome/html5?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, anchor

HTML5 makes it easy to open a phone app from a phone number in a web page:

```
<a href="tel:555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a>
```

I did a basic google search but I didn't find an equivalent simple way to open a map app from an address:

```
<a href="map:123 Main St Las Vegas, NV 89139">
123 Main St
Las Vegas, NV 89139
</a>
```

Is there an easy way to what I'm looking to do in modern browsers but I'm just missing it?  If not then what would be the simplest approach that people are generally using these days to support this type of functionality?

Comment: The simplest way would be to add a direct link to the full path URL of whatever map provider you want. There is no `map` protocol.

Comment: It depends on the URI scheme registered on the phone. (e.g. : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android )

Comment: The closest existing URI scheme is [`geo:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme): but it uses lat-long coordinates, is in a draft state, and doesn't have very wide support.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't hear about an easy way to implement that with  tag, I think using embedded code is easier for you and the user

[image]

Comment: but this implementation needs to be dynamic.  ie the address can be anything and when the user clicks on that address it should open in a map