# Openning an App on click of link in email in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send email with link to open Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697899/how-to-send-email-with-link-to-open-android-application)

I have a strange requirement for my project..

Suppose I have an app say **XYZ** installed in an android phone and than I receive an email from the mail server which contains a link like `http://XYZ.com/?params(i.e. X=1&Y=2&Z=3)` now on click of this link I want to open the **XYZ** app if it is installed in the phone and in the Activity I would like to get **these parameters X,Y and Z** and if the app is **not installed** user should be redirected to play store for downloading XYZ app and after installation app takes charge and behaves as if it was already installed (Opening the first activity with those parameters).

How can I achieve that ? I have no idea where to start so even the smallest pointer in right direction will be of great help.

Comment: you need to register for that intent. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388624/launch-activity-from-url

Comment: thanks @JamesM.. that link surely contains a part of question..

Comment: dont know why its not working on lollipop

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad and covers multiple aspects of Android SDK and web programming. Try breaking down your requirements into separate items and solving them individually:

1) If the app is present and the user clicks on a link in browser/email client. How do I make my app handle this link?

2) If the app is not installed, how to redirect users that click on a URL to the app installation page in Google Play?

3) How to extract parameters from a URL?

4) etc.

For the item #1 I would suggest looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870/1204377).

Comment: But How do I know whether the app is installed or not ?